# How to wrap functions with "...interface{}" argument (like Printf)

Tags: go

In my current project I am trying to write a logging function that will conditionally call fmt.Println.

My current Log function looks like this:

```
func Log(level int, a ...interface{}) {
    if level <= LogLevel {
        fmt.Println(a)
    }
}
```

But when I call it like this the output of Log gets encased in brackets for some reason:

http://play.golang.org/p/Aa8vC54Ih0

```
package main

import "fmt"

var LogLevel int

func main() {
    fmt.Println("string", 10, 3.1415926)
    LogLevel = 1
    Log(1, "string", 10, 3.1415926)
}

func Log(level int, a ...interface{}) {
    if level <= LogLevel {
        fmt.Println(a)
    }
}

string 10 3.1415926
[string 10 3.1415926]
```

This to me looks like the `a` argument in Log gets transformed somehow. How would I go about to pass `a` to fmt.Println in a way that is identical to calling fmt.Println directly?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Just change `fmt.Println(a)` to `fmt.Println(a...)`

See "Passing arguments to ... parameters" in the go spec http://golang.org/ref/spec#Passing_arguments_to_..._parameters

Comment: Thank you. I really should sit down and read through the whole spec some time.

Comment: Just to clarify, what you're doing when you do `fmt.Println(a)` is printing the array itself, so `Println` formats it to show that it's an array. When you do `fmt.Println(a...)`, it gets expanded into `fmt.Println(a[0], a[1], a[2])` and so on, which `Println` treats as a sequence of values rather than an array.

Answer (score 0):

The original question was not how to wrap a function so that it looks like Printf, but how to call such a function. But taking the original question subject verbatim, I came here looking for hints on creating and maintaining the wrappers.

In case you are wondering how to cope with some of the features that `go lint` provides, you can declare your homegrown functions that use printf style formatters, so that it checks that your format statement and arguments match.

For example,

```
func Infof(fmt string, args ...interface{}) {
    log.Printf("INFO"+fmt+"\n", args...)
}
func Warnf(fmt string, args ...interface{}) {
    log.Printf("WARN"+fmt+"\n", args...)
}

// this has a mistake, because there is no argument for %d    
Infof("Hello %s, can I help you with %d?", "Mark")
```

Run go vet like this;

```
go vet -printfuncs=InfoF,Warnf ./pkg/...
```

And it will tell you that your %d is missing an argument.